# java rhino: user send javascript expression <- security?

Tags: java, security, rhino

I'm writing a java application that will be executed on the server side using a **javascript** expression provided by the client and using java rhino. Is there a way to add a security layer to prevent rhino from using/accessing the filesystem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: Note that there is a newer JVM based Javascript runtime by Oracle called Nashorn which is supposed to be faster: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nashorn/

Comment: Nashorn is apparently faster under some circumstances but slower under others. Only runs on Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Rhino can be run under a "normal" Java `SecurityManager` and use the mechanisms used by Java to sandbox applications.

See [the Mozilla wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Overview) for details.

Comment: thanks. It is said "s. First, every Context that is created must be supplied an instance of an object that implements the SecuritySupport interface. " what is that interface ? I cannot find it.

Comment: That interface is obsolete and the documentation outdated. Look for ClassShutter (that will shut off access to a class) and SecurityController.